# Extreme cases are not passing for the question Weighted Uniform Strings

Tags: c++, vector

There is some fault in vector implementation, I guess but I am not able to figure it out with my knowledge. Can you help?
8/32 test case are failing (they are very big inputs)
This is problem link :
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weighted-uniform-string/problem
Here is my code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> weightedUniformStrings(string s, vector<int> queries) {
    int len=s.size();
    vector<int> count(26,0);
    
    vector<int> yesorno(queries.size(),0);
    for(int i=0;s[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        count[s[i] - 97] += s[i] - 96;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<(int)queries.size();i++)
    {
        if(queries[i] == 0)
        continue;
        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            if(((queries[i]%(j+1)) == 0) && (queries[i]<=count[j]))
            {
                yesorno[i]++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return yesorno;
}

int main()
{


    string s;
    cin>>s;


    int queries_count;
    cin>>queries_count;

    vector<int> queries(queries_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < queries_count; i++) {

        cin>>queries[i];
    }

    vector<int> result = weightedUniformStrings(s, queries);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        if(result[i] == 1)
        {
            cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        cout<<"No"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried various combinations of memory storage like long double, long long int but neither of them is working so it means there is some fault in the working of vectors.

Comment: Why calculate `len` and never use it? Why use `s[i] != '\0'` here `for(int i=0;s[i] != '\0';i++)` instead of just using the length of the string?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Constraints, it's not a problem of memory storage, type `int` is enough.

[image]

The following code snippet in your `weightedUniformStrings` function, it works well just basing on the condition that `the same characters are continuous`. Howerever, there is no such condition in this algorithm problem.

```cpp
    for(int i=0;s[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        count[s[i] - 97] += s[i] - 96;
    }
```

So **you need to consider the scenario where the same characters are not in consecutive positions**. Here is a sample.

```
abcdcdde
6
1
3
12
5
9
10
```